Gazebo Harmonic: GUI collapse button is broken
In Gazebo Harmonic there is a bar to the right side of the Entity Tree (a thin button from the top of the window to the bottom which becomes dark gray when putting the mouse there) which suggests the ability to collapse the Entity Tree and Model. However even when clicking, the Entity Tree and Model part of the GUI is still there blocking part of the 3D window, which is especially problematic when one is not interested in these parameters and Gazebo should be displayed together with Rviz side-by-side effectively. Is there a workaround for this bug?
